# How to access AWS API endpoints by java

Tags: java, web-services, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, endpoints

I am beginner of AWS and I have unclear points on connecting AWS API endpoints.
I was unable to access AWS API endpoints from java client. Every times, it failed.

- **May I know why it failed to connect?**
- **Is there any source code I can    reference to do?**

  ```
  public interface LamdaInterface {

      @LambdaFunction(functionName="GetCategoryAction")
      public List<LamdaOutput> getAllCategory(LamdaInput input);

  }

  public class LamdaTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      AWSCredentials credentails = new AWSCredentials() {

          @Override
          public String getAWSSecretKey() {
              // my aws secret key
              return "xxxx";
          }

          @Override
          public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
              // my aws access key Id
              return "xxx";
          }
      };

      AWSLambdaClient lambda = new AWSLambdaClient(credentails);
      lambda.configureRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);
      lambda.setEndpoint("https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/listall");

      LamdaInterface service = LambdaInvokerFactory.build(LamdaInterface.class, lambda);
      System.out.println("Calling...");
      List<LamdaOutput> list = service.getAllCategory(new LamdaInput());
      System.out.println("list : " + list);
      for (LamdaOutput l : list) {
          System.out.println("Name : " + l.getName());
      }
  }

  }
  ```

It failed by this error.

```
Calling...


Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection timed out: connect  
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:642)    
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:400)    
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:362) 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:311)  
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:1925) 
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:1029) 
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaInvokerFactory$LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvokerFactory.java:121) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getAllCategory(Unknown Source)    
    at testPrj.LamdaTest.main(LamdaTest.java:43) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Even though I tried to connect from the browser, it failed. It is GET request so I don't need to pass any request parameters.

```
https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/listall

Error is : **{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}**
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to invoke your lambda function at the URL you are setting as the endpoint.  The endpoint is where the *API client* sends it's API calls.  It is not related to where you'd browse to invoke your lambda.  The valid lambda endpoints are listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#lambda_region.  Incidentally, you should either set the endpoint, or call `setRegion`/`configureRegion`, but not both.

To invoke your lambda, use the `invoke()` API call on [`com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html) or the AWS CLI (`aws lambda invoke --function-name GetCategoryAction`).

If you want to make your lambda accessible on the web as an API, you might want to look at the Amazon API Gateway service.